# Java collection with Class Object does not work

Tags: java, linked-list

this is my simply code in java:

```
 public class Book {
 private String title;
 private int year;

 public Book(String title, int year){
     this.title=title;
     this.year=year;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
     return title;
 }

 public int getYear() {
     return year;
 }
}
```

```
public class Library {

   private LinkedList listOfBooks=new LinkedList<Book>();

   public void addBook(Book book){
       listOfBooks.add(book);
   }

   public LinkedList getListOfBooks(){
       return listOfBooks;
   }
}
```

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Library library=new Library();
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 1", 1995));
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 2", 2015));
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 3", 1998));
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 4", 2011));
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 5", 2020));
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 6", 2021));
        library.addBook(new Book("Title 7", 1999));

        Book book1=library.getListOfBooks().get(2);

    }
}
```

Why the " Book book1=library.getListOfBooks().get(2);" is wrong ?
when I call library.getListOfBooks() I suppose to get LinkedList with Book Objects, so when I call:
library.getListOfBooks().get(2) i suppose to get Book Object.
Am I wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: You are using a raw type in `public LinkedList getListOfBooks()`. use `LinkedList<Book>` instead like you did in the declaration

Comment: The compiler prints warnings about your use of raw types.  Pay attention to compiler warnings.  Don’t just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

You've used raw LinkedList in the Library class. That is why the `getListOfBooks()` returned linked list of objects, and the `get(2)` returned an object which you're trying to assign to the `book1` variable.

Just modify the variable declaration and pass specific type to the linkedList, that'll work properly.

```
private LinkedList<Book> listOfBooks = new LinkedList<Book>();
```

Also change the return type of the function `getListOfBooks`:

```
public LinkedList<Book> getListOfBooks() {
    return listOfBooks;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It is clear for me now :)

Comment: @Angie0147,  if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.